# NPE Exception when using Mockito+Kotlin in Quakrus project

Tags: kotlin, mockito, quarkus

I tried to use Kotlin in my Quarkus example project, but when writing tests with Mockito for the resource tests, it is always failed.

Example project codes: https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/tree/master/mongodb-kotlin-co

Given the following tests.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `get post by id`() {
        val id = ObjectId()
        `when`(postRepository.findById(any(ObjectId::class.java)))
            .thenReturn(
                Uni.createFrom().item(
                    Post(id, "foo", "bar", LocalDateTime.now()),
                )
            )

        //@formatter:off
        given()
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
        .`when`()
            .get("/posts/$id")
        .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .log().all()
            .body( "title", `is`("foo"))
        //@formatter:on

        verify(postRepository, times(1)).findById(any(ObjectId::class.java))
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(postRepository)
    }
```

The argument `any(ObjectId::class.java))` throws a NPE exception.

```kotlin
java.lang.NullPointerException: any(ObjectId::class.java) must not be null

    at com.example.PostResourcesTest.get post by id(PostResourcesTest.kt:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
```

The Mockito requires the `findById` is a `open`(aka final in Java) fun, which is from Quakrus internal Repository interface. I have already added `all-open`, `no-arg` plugin in the Kotlin maven plugin, see [here](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/blob/master/mongodb-kotlin-co/pom.xml#L225), but it is still failed.

But I am sure the same code style in a Spring Boot project is working well, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-kotlin/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/PostControllerTests.kt#L52-L66

**Update**: The similar Java version of the testing codes are working well, see: https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/blob/master/resteasy-classic/src/test/java/com/example/PostResourceTest.java

Comment: Does it work when using simply `any()`?